# Expand width of parent when zoom in and scroll-x for parent div

Tags: html, css, position, width, zooming

I've one parent div and 3 child div. When zoom in the browser, i want the parent div to have scroll x while position of the child content still remain, what happend to me now is when I zoom in the browser, `child-div3` move below `child-div2`. below I illustrate the css and html

```
body{padding: 0 5px;margin: 0;min-width: 1280px;overflow: auto;}
div#parent{min-width: 1280px;overflow-x:scroll;overflow-y:hidden;}
div#parent div{position: relative;}
div#child-div1{height:500px;width:480px;margin-top: 10px;float: left;}
div#child-div2{float:left; max-width: 600px;max-height: 500px;}
div#child-div3{height:500px;width:480px;margin-top: 10px;float: left;}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="parent">
        <div id="child-div1">
            content..
        </div>
        <div id="child-div2">
            <img border="0" src="../images/images.png" alt="" width="600px" height="500px" />
        </div>
        <div id="child-div3">
            content..
        </div>
    </div>
<body>
```

here with sample [code](http://jsfiddle.net/intoxicatedcandle/JVYxH/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because `div#child-div1.width()+div#child-div2.width()+div#child-div3.width()>screen.width()` , I reduced these widths and it worked correctly. I recommend you to use `px` for parent `DIV` and `%` for child `div`. it always works